# Is there any way to pass adapter in intent?

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization

I have a dataclass of Kotlin as

```
class Exercises (
var adapter: LabsAdapter? = null,

@SerializedName("id") val id : Int,
@SerializedName("group") val group : String,
@SerializedName("title") val title : String,
@SerializedName("description") val description : String,
@SerializedName("image_path") val image_path : String,
@SerializedName("video_path") val video_path : String,
@SerializedName("created_at") val created_at : String,
@SerializedName("updated_at") val updated_at : String,
@SerializedName("pivot") val pivot : Pivot
):Serializable
```

But there is an adapter and it's not getting serialized and giving the following error :

java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object

Comment: If you want to do this, then yours LabsAdapter should be also Serializable. Maybe instead of passing adapter you could pass simple List<> ? Can you please add LabsAdapter code to your question and more details about why you want pass whole adapter in intent?

Comment: No, I am not passing Lab Adapter I am passing Exercises, I have also made LabAdapter Serializable. 
While passing Exercise I am getting this error

Comment: But in yours Exercises class you have field `var adapter: LabsAdapter? = null`. Is LabsAdapter serializable in this case?

Comment: You shouldn't pass adapter in the intent. Replace it with list of data.